How to configure JOOQ to pass hex strings instead of octal for bytea column insertion in PostgreSQL?
We are using JOOQ to insert records into postgresql table with bytea column.
The byte array we are sending is about 150Mb and we are getting an error from Postgresql server:

ERROR: invalid memory alloc request size 1073741824.

After digging into the code and the query JOOQ is generating, we noticed that the byteArray is converted into octal (org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresUtils#toPGString(byte[]))
And the query ends up looking something like:
INSERT INTO test_table (my_data) VALUES (E'\\042\\145\\171...\\042'::bytea);

Testing with smaller byte arrays revels that after the data is inserted, its size is indeed the size of the byte array and not the size of the octal string (which is much longer).
The issue seems to be that the octal string is so long that postgresql server fails on casting it to bytea even before trying to save it to the column.
Is there a way to configure JOOQ to pass hex string as Value instead of octal?
We are using JOOQ version 3.16.4 and postgresql 13.9
Clarification edit:
JOOQ is configured with the default DefaultConfiguration. No significant changes are done.
The sql above is taken from the exception thrown in:
org.jooq.impl.Tools#translate(java.lang.String, java.lang.RuntimeException)
And the sql that it prints looks like that:
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "public"."table_name" ("id", "name", "version", "description", "archived", "other_id", "jws_data") values (829720463911690240, 'v-0', 'rb-0-6HW7', null, 0, 829720463899107328, E'\\042\\145\\171\\112\\162\\141\\127\\....\135\\175'::bytea) returning "public"."table_name"."id"]; Unspecified RuntimeException
We are not generating the SQL insert, instead we are using org.jooq.impl.DAOImpl#insert(P) and pass a JOOQ generated Record object that holds the byteArray as one of the members (jws_data). this name also corresponds to the column name in the table.
Note: I changed the SQL a bit to hide the exact column names so please ignore the names and the mismatch to the other SQLs.
StackTrace:
    toPGString:631, PostgresUtils (org.jooq.util.postgres)
    sqlInline0:2044, DefaultBinding$DefaultBytesBinding (org.jooq.impl)
    sqlInline0:1941, DefaultBinding$DefaultBytesBinding (org.jooq.impl)
    sql:937, DefaultBinding$AbstractBinding (org.jooq.impl)
    sql:929, DefaultBinding$AbstractBinding (org.jooq.impl)
    accept:186, Val (org.jooq.impl)
    visit0:720, DefaultRenderContext (org.jooq.impl)
    visit:295, AbstractContext (org.jooq.impl)
    toSQL92Values:326, FieldMapsForInsert (org.jooq.impl)
    toSQL92Values:278, FieldMapsForInsert (org.jooq.impl)
    accept:137, FieldMapsForInsert (org.jooq.impl)
    visit0:720, DefaultRenderContext (org.jooq.impl)
    visit:295, AbstractContext (org.jooq.impl)
    toSQLInsert:739, InsertQueryImpl (org.jooq.impl)
    accept0:624, InsertQueryImpl (org.jooq.impl)
    accept:642, AbstractDMLQuery (org.jooq.impl)
    visit0:720, DefaultRenderContext (org.jooq.impl)
    visit:295, AbstractContext (org.jooq.impl)
    getSQL0:484, AbstractQuery (org.jooq.impl)
    execute:287, AbstractQuery (org.jooq.impl)
    storeInsert0:191, TableRecordImpl (org.jooq.impl)
    lambda$storeInsert$0:157, TableRecordImpl (org.jooq.impl)
    apply:-1, TableRecordImpl$$Lambda$2120/0x0000000801a5bef8 (org.jooq.impl)
    operate:143, RecordDelegate (org.jooq.impl)
    storeInsert:156, TableRecordImpl (org.jooq.impl)
    insert:144, TableRecordImpl (org.jooq.impl)
    insert:139, TableRecordImpl (org.jooq.impl)
    insert:180, DAOImpl (org.jooq.impl)
    insert:156, DAOImpl (org.jooq.impl)
    save:80, RDBDao (org.jfrog.bintray.distribution.rdb)


Same behaviour can be reproduced by calling:
dslContext.insertInto(TEST_TABLE)
          .set(MY_DATA, jws_data_byte_array)
          .execute();

Or
dslContext.execute("insert into test_table (my_data) values (?)", jws_data_byte_array);

Same toPGString:631, PostgresUtils (org.jooq.util.postgres) is triggered.

Why are you inlining bind values?

Surely you should be using PreparedStatement::setBinaryStream?

The query i provided is just an example of how the query looks,
We are using DAOImpl.insert() with generated Record  objects

The "real" query sent is a bit longer with many more params:
insert into "public"."our_table" ("id", "name", "version", "description", "archived", "other_id", "jws_data") values (829720463911690240, 'v-0', 'rb-0-6HW7', null, 0, 829720463899107328, E'\\042\\145\\171\\112\\162\\141\\127\\121\\151\\117\\1...)

@EliSkoran: jOOQ always generates PreparedStatement with bind values by default. Why is your bind value getting inlined? How did you configure jOOQ, and why?

@LukasEder Thanks for the reply, please see the clarification edit to the post.

@EliSkoran: but my question is still: why are your bind values getting inlined? Can you post the call stack that leads to (org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresUtils#toPGString(byte[]))?

@LukasEder Added the stack trace.

It seems you're using an old version of jOOQ, but that probably doesn't matter. Your dslContext is quite likely configured to inline bind values. Please, do investigate this. There's no good reason why this call stack would be chosen otherwise (from DefaultBinding$AbstractBinding.sql() to DefaultBinding$DefaultBytesBinding.sqlInline0(). You can set a breakpoint there, or go up the call stack to see where e.g. Settings.statementType is set to STATIC_STATEMENT, or Settings.paramType  is set to INLINED (there could be other reasons, too). Perhaps your third party RDBDao does this?

As @Lukas Eder mentioned,
We have found a place where the statementType was changed to STATIC_STATEMENT instead of the default PREPARED_STATEMENT.
After removing this config JOOQ stoped creating the long octal strings and the insert works perfectly.
